# Почему теряется качество фоновой картинки?

Tags: css

Вставлю картинку png (1920x1080) в background и теряется качество картинки. Почему так происходит.  Помогите исправить

```
.container{
background-image: url(images/background-photo.jpg);      
background-position: center center;      
background-repeat: no-repeat;      
background-attachment: fixed;      
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Теряется из-за cover - пиксельная картинка растягивается, потому так.

Comment: а что делать тогда ?

Comment: Что делать зависит от того, какой нужен результат.

Comment: @Эникейщик чтобы был фон без потери качества

Comment: Тогда ``background-size: auto;``. Изображение будет показано в оригинальном размере. Но часть его будет невидна или же часть экрана останется без фона (если экран  больше 1920х1080).

Answer (score 1):

Кстати, cover лучше прописывать и для остальных, если что:

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
```

Есть решения другие - например,

1. ставить бОльший размер.
2. Использовать решения интерполяции (правда, поддержка еще не везде ахти)

   ```
   image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges; /* Firefox */
   -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;  /* IE */
   image-rendering: crisp-edges; /* Стандартное свойство */
   ```
3. Попробовать svg - правда, тут есть моменты...
4. Попробовать, в комплексе, оптимизацию графики для Retina-экранов через соотношение между физическими и CSS-пикселями (device-pixel-ratio)

Конечно, в идеале, вообще-то, вектор и только вектор дает безграничные возможности масштабирования.

В общем, получается - нужно давать картинку нужного заведомо большего размера для большинства предполагаемых отображений/устройств.